# How is the inline specifier used in C++ to preserve the one definition rule?

Tags: c++, namespaces, constants, linkage, one-definition-rule

I've been trying to figure out how the `inline` specifier preserves ODR. So far, with everything I've written it seems unnecessary because include guards ensure that definitions are only included once.

Suppose I have the following definition in a file called `constants.h`

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

namespace constants {
    inline const double pi { 3.14159255358979323846 };
    inline const double e  { 2.71828182845904523536 };
}

#endif
```

From my understanding of `inline` in relation to the ODR, the `inline` specifier is written to ensure that the definition of these constants are only initialized once across multiple translation units. So if I include this file in `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` everything should be good.

Now, let's remove the `inline` keyword.

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

namespace constants {
    const double pi { 3.14159255358979323846 };
    const double e  { 2.71828182845904523536 };
}

#endif
```

Now if I include this in `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` no issues. I guess this is because of the include guards which ensure multiple definitions of the same thing don't occur twice.

Next, let's remove the include guards

```
namespace constants {
    const double pi { 3.14159255358979323846 };
    const double e  { 2.71828182845904523536 };
}
```

Still no problem. Maybe because `const` qualified variable definitions have internal linkage by default. As a result, including `constants.h` in `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` makes each of these definitions internal by default to their respective translation units.

Having a hard time breaking ODR across multiple translation units. Let's remove const now.

```
namespace constants {
    double pi { 3.14159255358979323846 };
    double e  { 2.71828182845904523536 };
}
```

NOW! ODR is broken across multiple translation units. Let's try fixing this with `inline` so that the compiler knows to only define these variables once.

```
namespace constants {
    inline double pi { 3.14159255358979323846 };
    inline double e  { 2.71828182845904523536 };
}
```

Ok, no more errors, this file can once again be included in multiple translation units. So why is considered "best practice" to declare constants in header files as `inline`? It seems to take a lot of effort to break ODR and `inline` is redundant in the presence of include guards.

Comment: As long as - "_...each definition consists of the __same sequence of tokens__ (typically, appears in the same header file)..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition  .  Also breaking ODR is no _"diagnostic required"_ ie you can break it and the compiler / linker does not have to report any errors / warnings - just you now have Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @RichardCritten `inline` variables are excluded from ODR, it isn't UB to have multiple definitions if the definition is `inline`. ODR says : *"One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined."*

Comment: Include guards protect you from including header content more than once in the *same* translation unit. They do nothing across translation units. `inline` protects you from having multiple definitions *across* translation units. It does (just about) nothing within a single translation unit.

Comment: The above are correct. However you should also be marking your compile-time constants as 'inline constexpr' (if constexpr is available on your compiler) Marking these as 'inline constexpr' will (likely) in-line the literal values where ever they're needed saving a lot of mov instructions. If this code is part of a library and you want to preserve these constants for external access, make them as 'constexpr volatile'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constants that are not declared with the specifier extern have internal linkage.

So all compilation units that include these declarations

```
namespace constants {
    const double pi { 3.14159255358979323846 };
    const double e  { 2.71828182845904523536 };
}
```

have their own constants pi and e.

From the C++ 14 Standard (3.5 Program and linkage)

> 3 A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is
> the name of
>
> (3.2) — a variable of non-volatile const-qualified type that is
> neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to have
> external linkage; or

Opposite to the above declarations these declarations

```
namespace constants {
    double pi { 3.14159255358979323846 };
    double e  { 2.71828182845904523536 };
}
```

have external linkage. So the compiler issues an error if these declarations (that are also definitions) are included in more than one compilation unit because the one definition rule is broken.

You could make the above variables to have the internal linkage if you declare them in an unnamed namespace as for example

```
namespace constants {
    namespace {
        double pi { 3.14159255358979323846 };
        double e  { 2.71828182845904523536 };
    }
}
```

As for these declarations

```
namespace constants {
    inline double pi { 3.14159255358979323846 };
    inline double e  { 2.71828182845904523536 };
}
```

then inline variables with external linkage may be defined in more than one compilation unit. Moreover an inline variable shall be defined in each compilation unit where it is ODR-used.